# success rate/probability distribution and uncertainty

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, binomial-distribution

Apologies if this is a question, which is too basic. Despite many google searches, I could not find an answer. Let us say I have a biased coin and success is defined as head. Is there a way to determine the standard error/confidence interval (e.g. +/- 1.96 * se/standard deviation?) around the observed success rate, depending on the number of observations? So if the coin was tossed only 3 times, the confidence interval would be larger than if I tossed it 100 times. I would think this is somewhat related to the binomial distribution but I am interested in the success rate rather than number of successes. I am familiar with bootstrapping, so resampling from the observations may also be an option? Thanks.

Comment: If $\hat{p}$ represents the proportion of heads among your $n$ trials, a standard $100(1-\alpha)$% confience interval for the true probability of getting heads on a single trial, denoted $p$, is given by $$\hat{p} \pm z_{\alpha/2}\sqrt{\frac{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}{n}}$$ The usual requirement is that you observe at least ten heads and at least ten tails among your sample (this is called the "normal condition").

Comment: @MatthewPilling is there a link/text book for the above please. is z coming from the z-score normal distribution? Thanks!